# How to install GTK2 with JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby

Could any one help me with this problem, When i am trying to install GTk2 gem in Jruby??

```
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.

checking for -Wall option to compiler... no

checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... no

checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... no


checking for -Wextra option to compiler... no

checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... no

checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... no

checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... no

checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... no

checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... no

checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... no

checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... no

checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... no

checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... no

checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... no

checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... no

checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... no

checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... no

checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... no

checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... no

checking for -Wundef option to compiler... no

checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... no

checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... no

checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... IOError: Cannot run program "cc" (in directory "C:\jruby-1.6.8\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\glib2-1.1.5\ext\glib2"):
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

            popen at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3613

           xpopen at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:323

             open at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260

           xpopen at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:316

        egrep_cpp at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:538

        have_func at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:758

     checking_for at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:652

         postpone at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:286

             open at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260

         postpone at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:286

             open at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260

         postpone at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:282

     checking_for at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:651

        have_func at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:755

  check_ruby_func at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glib2-1.1.5/lib/mkmf-gnome2.rb:369

           (root) at C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glib2-1.1.5/lib/mkmf-
gnome2.rb:558

          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062

           (root) at extconf.rb:15
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.


Provided configuration options:

        --with-opt-dir

        --without-opt-dir

        --with-opt-include

        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include

        --with-opt-lib

        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib

        --with-make-prog

        --without-make-prog

        --srcdir=.

        --curdir

        --ruby=C:/jruby-1.6.8/bin/jruby    

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glib2-1.1.5 for inspection.

Results logged to C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glib2-1.1.5/ext/glib2/gem_make.out
```

I got ruined by this problem... Actually i want to run Real multi-threading in ruby... Already i have coded an application that uses GTk in ruby... Now i want to port that application to JRuby.....

Please help me... any one have short out this before>>?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that you either don't have a C compiler installed or if you do it can't find it

> IOError: Cannot run program "cc"

So it looks like GTK is trying to build native extensions, which aren't supported very well in Jruby. This blog post discusses some code he's written to use gtk+ from Jruby https://wordpress.kaspernj.org/?p=85

Since you're porting over to Jruby you could also use the Java GTK directly or also use SWT directly.  There's a gem for SWT https://github.com/danlucraft/swt which includes a few simple examples not sure how complete it is though.

As a sidenote the [Redcar Editor](http://redcareditor.com/) is written in Jruby + SWT

Answer (score 1):

You could try the FFI bindings for Gtk3. I have used them from both normal Ruby and JRuby myself. The gems are named "gir_ffi" and "gir_ffi-gtk".

However, you be aware, that there currently are some threadding problems under MRI Ruby, which you will have to hack yourself out of, like I have done here:

https://github.com/kaspernj/gtk3assist/blob/master/lib/gtk3assist_threadding.rb

Also this library is basically extracted directly from the C library, thus making it much more complicated than the normal Ruby GTK library. I have tried to make it a bit simpler, but there is a long way to go to make it as easy and simple as the Ruby GTK2 library:

https://github.com/kaspernj/gtk3assist/tree/master/lib

This could be the multi-Ruby and multi-OS GUI lib we have all been waiting for :-) I have gotten it working under both Linux and Mac (haven't tried it on Windows yet).